# Bind data to nested grid in footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, footer, buttonclick

I have added programatically button to the footer in RowDataBound:

```
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Total: ";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = totalStaff.ToString();
        Button showStaff = new Button();
        showStaff.CommandName = "ShowAll";
        showStaff.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(showStaff);
        e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        showStaff.Click += new EventHandler(showStaff_Click);
    }
```

now I want to handle showStaff_Click to bind data to nested gridview. I wrote bwlow code in RowCommand but index is null:

```
            if(e.CommandName == "ShowAll")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                
                GridViewRow row = Staff.Rows[index];
                GridView StaffInfo = (GridView)Staff.Rows[index].FindControl("StaffInfo"); 
                int TeamID = 0;
                int cityID = 3699;
                StaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityID, TeamID);
                StaffInfo.DataBind();
            }
```

I will appreciate Your help.

EDIT:

I have nade some changes:

```
    protected void Staff_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Checking for command name which command/button is pressed
        if (e.CommandName == "ShowDetails")
        {
            GridView Staff = (GridView)sender;

            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = Staff.Rows[index];
            GridView StaffInfo = (GridView)Staff.Rows[index].FindControl("StaffInfo");
            int TeamID = Convert.ToInt16(Staff.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString());
            int cityID = Convert.ToInt16(Staff.DataKeys[index].Values[1].ToString());
            StaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityID, TeamID);
            StaffInfo.DataBind();
            StaffInfo.Visible = true;
        }
        else if(e.CommandName == "ShowAll")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridView StaffInfo = (GridView)Staff.Rows[index].FindControl("StaffInfo");
            int TeamID = 0;
            int cityID = 3699;
            StaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityID, TeamID);
            StaffInfo.DataBind();
            StaffInfo.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}

<asp:GridView ID="Staff" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
    OnRowCommand="Staff_RowCommand" 
    DataKeyNames="TeamID,CityID" ShowFooter="True" HorizontalAlign="Center">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Function">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label Width="150px" ID="Function" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Function") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:GridView ID="StaffInfo" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"> 
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"  />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="SOEID" HeaderText="SOEID" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>                 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Team">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label Width="150px" ID="Team" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Team") %>'></asp:Label> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Staff Count">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button Width="40px" ID="StaffCount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StaffCount") %>' CommandName="ShowDetails" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" CausesValidation="True" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />                   
        </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button id="TotalStaff" runat="server" Text="Button1" CommandName="ShowAll" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" CausesValidation="True" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
            </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField Visible ="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Width="150px" DataField="TeamID" HeaderText="TeamID" ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField> 
    <asp:TemplateField Visible ="false">
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <asp:Label runat="server" ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CityID" HeaderText="CityID"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

When I try to click the ShowAll button ite returns that index is out of range. I made Response.Write(intex.ToString()) and it returns -1. The index number in case or row is returned correctly. The problem is with footer button. Could You please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set `CommandArgument` when you crated your button.

```
Button showStaff = new Button();
showStaff.CommandName = "ShowAll";
showStaff.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
showStaff.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
```

Comment: I have added and have tehe error: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Comment: Check if your grid has rows when you are inside click event (put breakpoint on `GridViewRow row = Staff.Rows[index];` this line and see how many rows it has and what is the index) it should help you out.

Comment: I set breakpoint in place You wanted and it returned that CommandArgument = -1